# can we apply date range filter on date if date data type or dtype is text or str?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

```
models-
`class RocCharge(models.Model):`
`charge_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`
`chname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)`
`date_of_creation = models.TextField(default=date.today)`

views-
`from_date = request.GET.get('fromdate')`
`to_date = request.GET.get('Todate')`
`if from_date and to_date:
    combined_data = combined_data.filter(date_of_creation__gte=from_date, date_of_creation__lte=to_date)`
```

my date of creation in mysql as well as in models in text format , but i want to perform date range filter from to range without changing date data type , my date in mysql like-21-12-2019

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

from_date_str = request.GET.get('fromdate')
to_date_str = request.GET.get('Todate')

if from_date_str and to_date_str:
    # Define possible date formats
    date_formats = ["%d-%m-%Y", "%Y-%m-%d", "%d/%m/%Y", "%Y/%m/%d"]

    # Try parsing the date strings using different formats
    for date_format in date_formats:
        try:
            from_date = datetime.strptime(from_date_str, date_format)
            to_date = datetime.strptime(to_date_str, date_format)
            break  # Exit the loop if parsing succeeds
        except ValueError:
            continue  # Try the next format if parsing fails

    # Filter based on the datetime range
    combined_data = combined_data.filter(date_of_creation__range=(from_date, to_date))
```

Comment: hi , i tried but showing errror-File 
   , in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2015-01-01' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'
[01/Mar/2024 10:06:46] "GET /centralapp/Home/?existing_old=&fromdate=01-01-2022&Todate=03-03-2023&amount=&amount__lt=&amount__gt=&sorting=&sorting_cmpny=&sorting_date=&sorting_amt=&sorting_city=&existing_old=&fromdate=2015-01-01&Todate=2024-03-01&amount=&amount__lt=&amount__gt=&sorting=&sorting_cmpny=&sorting_date=&sorting_amt=&sorting_city= HTTP/1.1" 500 85898

Comment: also i tried to change url to change url directly from web - this acctual url- http://127.0.0.1:8000/centralapp/Home/?existing_old=&fromdate=2015-02-09&Todate=2023-08-07&amount=&amount__lt=&amount__gt=&sorting=&sorting_cmpny=&sorting_date=&sorting_amt=&sorting_city= , to this -http://127.0.0.1:8000/centralapp/Home/?existing_old=&fromdate=01-01-2015&Todate=03-03-2023&amount=&amount__lt=&amount__gt=&sorting=&sorting_cmpny=&sorting_date=&sorting_amt=&sorting_city=  but showing nothing or blank in pg

Comment: Its because date format is mismatched , i have updated the code check that, Make sure you are using correct format while getting the data